# TIdPeerThreadとTIdThreadのクラスの内容が同じかどうかどうか調べたい。

Tags: c++

Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.3のコミュニティー版をインストールして、Borland C++ Builder6で作成された時のプロジェクトを開いてビルドを行ってみました。
ビルドを実施すると複数箇所で次のようなエラーが発生しました。

> [bcc32c エラー] Main.cpp(2761): unknown type name 'TIdPeerThread'

この　TIdPeerThread　のところにカーソルを置くと、TIdThread　という候補が表示されました。

この2つのクラスの内容はほぼ同じ内容なのかをを確認したいのですが、
このクラスの詳細を確認できるサイトをご教示頂きますよう、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `Indy9 TIdPeerThread`で検索するとこんなのが出てきます。[TIdPeerThread](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007613.html), [TIdThread](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007846.html) Indy10では無くなっているようですね。[Indy10でのTIdTcp使用法](http://delphidevelop.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-5.html), [migrating from Indy9 to Indy10](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/11/510262.html)

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。こちらの(http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007613.html)TIdPeerThreadのサイトですが、TIdPeerThread = class(TIdThread)　このような記述がありますが、TIdPeerThreadというのは、TIdThreadクラスの一部という意味なのでしょうか？

Comment: 何かそのサイトあるいはDelphi独特の表記なのでは？ ここ [Indy 9](https://www.indyproject.org/download/v9/) からソースが入手できるようなので、調べてみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。ソース見てみたいです。それと、TIdContextに関するdocwikiっていうサイトはありますでしょうか？

Comment: TIdPeerThreadというクラス？はIndy10からはTIdContextというのに変更されているという話をみました。少し気になっています。

Comment: ちょっと検索した程度では見つからないですね。[Index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/Index) があって飛んだら [Indy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/Indy) の概要でした。